# Upload custom templates in django

Tags: django, django-templates

I want users to be able, to **upload their custom html templates** including css styling and png and jpeg images. These html files shall be retrievable through django. That means that they can see the resulting html content in form of a normal webpage. In order to be able to do that, I (seemingly, don't know a better approach yet) have to upload the html files in the template directory.

This is my current model:

```
class StylesheetFile(models.Model):
    HTML = 'HTML'
    CSS  = 'CSS'
    JPEG = 'JPEG'
    PNG  = 'PNG'

    # Currently supported mimetypes
    MIMETYPE_CHOICES = (
        (HTML, 'text/html' ),
        (CSS , 'text/css'  ),
        (JPEG, 'image/jpeg'),
        (PNG , 'image/png' ),
    )

    mimetype = models.CharField(max_length=64, choices = MIMETYPE_CHOICES)
    company = models.ForeignKey(Company)
    file = models.FileField(upload_to=get_upload_path)
```

And this is the current function to determine the upload_path:

```
def get_upload_path(instance, filename):
    if instance.mimetype == 'HTML':
        return os.path.join(
            settings.TEMPLATES[0]['DIRS'][1],
            instance.company.name,
            filename)
    if instance.mimetype == 'CSS':
        return os.path.join(
            "custom_css",
            instance.company.name,
            filename)
    if instance.mimetype == 'JPEG' or instance.mimetype == 'PNG':
        return os.path.join(
            "custom_img",
            instance.company.name,
            filename)
```

Template settings

```
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [
            '/home/ubuntu/app/templates/',
            '/home/ubuntu/app/custom_templates',
        ],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]
```

When I do this the css stylings, png and jpeg files are getting uploaded correctly, but the html files not. I receive following error:

```
The joined path (/home/ubuntu/app/custom_templates/FooCompany/factors.html) is located outside of the base path component (/home/ubuntu/app/static/media)
```

What can I do to prevent this error? Is there some best practice approach to my problem or do I have to go for some workaround like setting one of m y TEMPLATE_DIRS to `/home/ubuntu/app/static/media/custom_templates`. Maybe this is not even a workaround and legit practice.. I don't know really know.. Help is appreciated a lot!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot use `FileField` to upload files outside of `MEDIA_ROOT`. That's an important security measure.

You could set `TEMPLATE_DIRS` to something inside `MEDIA_ROOT` and most likely this would work, but this makes my cringe really hard. That would essentially gave the users an ability to overwrite *any* template for *any*  page on the site.

You don't have to save those templates as HTML files to use them as Django templates. You can save them in a database and render them directly from string:

```
from django.template import engines
from django.http import HttpResponse

# Get the template from database
template_from_db = YourCustomTemplateModel.objects.get(name='homepage')
template_string = template_from_db.content

# Create a django Template object
template = engines['django'].from_string(template_string)

# Render the template to a string
context = {'foo': 'bar'}
page_content = template.render(context=context)

# Send page to a the browser
return HttpResponse(page_content)
```

You should however think really hard about the security implications of doing this in general. Are you really comfortable with template creators being able to set arbitrary JavaScript on your domain (think *cross-site scripting* vulnerability)? What about calling arbitrary methods (or at least the ones not having any arguments) and accessing arbitrary arguments on objects you pass in the `context` dictionary?

Comment: First of all, thank you a lot for your answer! I already thought about the security issues on this one but my superior told me to write a function to check for javascript and don't allow it (I hope this is as easy as it sounds). So the user shall be basically just allowed to upload html css and jpg and png. No javascript at all

Comment: Removing JavaScript is not easy at all. Not in a secure way that can not be circumvented by a clever attacker. Actually that's a really hard problem.

Comment: JS is not the only issue. You can execute queries in a template and flood database connection or get sensitive data. What about `{% for friend in user.friends %}{{ friend.password }} {{ friend.email }}{% endfor %}` or `{% for a in user.friends %}{% for b in a.friends %}{% for c in b.friends %}{% endfor %}{% endfor %}{% endfor %}`

Comment: As for removing JavaScript. For example given this string: `<scr<script></script>ipt>alert('attack!');</scr<script></script>ipt>` a naive implementation would strip `<script></script>` and would end up with `<script>alert('attack!');</sript>`, which is still JavaScript. There are plenty different of tricks like that, most of them more subtle. Besides that JavaScript can be embedded on a page in many different ways (think about the `onclick`, `onhover` etc. attributes that can be put on any tag). To make things worse: many browsers will execute JavaScript even if the declaration is malformed.

Comment: @AntoinePinsard is of course right. That's the problem with accessing arbitrary arguments and calling arbitrary methods (!) I wrote about in my post. That's also a reason for a concern.

Comment: Oh man that bums me out... This is my final project for my school (I'm doing a thing called Ausbildung in Germany) that my superior had selected for me.. But thank you a lot for pointing that out guys!

Comment: You should be able to explain and convince him that this is not a good idea to do so. He may not be aware about this. Discuss with him about the issues and see if you can find an alternative, abort this feature, or implement it anyway. If you inform him about the flaws and he tells you to do it anyway, it his his responsibility. If you do it without warning him, it is your responsibility.

Comment: If you absolutely have to do this you could try using [the Mozilla Bleach library](https://github.com/mozilla/bleach) to **whitelist** couple of selected and safe HTML tags and attributes. Everything **not** on the list should be removed. Bleach will help you with that. To mitigate the concerns voiced by @AntoinePinsard you should pass to variables in the `context` dictionary only simple built-in types like strings and numbers (or list of those types). Not queryset or model objects like you would normally do. And even after this I still feel uneasy about the whole thing.

Comment: @AntoinePinsard is right again. I wanted to write about that in a separate comment, but he expressed it much better than I would. You should definitely talk with your supervisor and voice all your concerns.

Comment: @LudwikTrammer I definitely will talk to him about this issue! Unfortunately he is in meetings the whole day. Thank you a lot for bleach, I think this will help a little bit. I already thought about just letting the users send me their files and me checking and uploading them eventually. But if a user would send me 20 css and html pages that would be a lot of time invested and not really worth it..

Comment: Also the type of html page they upload will always have the same structure. They will upload a so called "Berichtsheft" which is a file what contains a report of the weekly tasks completed. According to official instructions the content has to be the same, so I thought about just creating a static default HTML template with divs or id's, which they can use to apply their css..

Comment: Allowing user to only change CSS would be a very sensible approach. CSS is really powerful when it comes to specifying designs (see: http://www.csszengarden.com). You would still need to sanitise it, but most severe problems would be gone.